# How Can I Use Classic ASP Session Object in ASP.NET to Read Session Variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, com, asp-classic, vbscript

Background:

1. I'm developing an ASP.NET application for a classic ASP website
2. User authentication is performed by the classic ASP website
3. The classic ASP website stores data in session variables to identify authenticated users
4. I need to read the data in those session variables in my ASP.NET application

Many articles say that you need to store session state in a database in order to do this.

None of them have mentioned about using VBScript objects from within the VB.NET code.

**Is it possible to do this? Can I not simply reference a COM library in my application and use the objects and their methods? If not, how come?**

Comment: How are you running your ASP classic and ASP.NET applications? Are they part of the same webb application (share the same web.config) or are they in separate directories?

Comment: Its a crazy setup: the root website is an ASP.NET website, which contains a classic ASP website as a virtual folder, and I've added my ASP.NET website within that virtual folder as an "application" in IIS :)

Comment: Then I think that you're ASP.NET site runs totally separate from the ASP classic site. I think you have to configure your ASP.NET sub site to not be an own application. There are some compatibility settings for ASP.NET that I think allows both ASP classic and ASP.NET to work in the same application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session variable values are not just the result of a function call. They depend on IIS and other tools to uniquely identify the user. It isn't possible to directly retrieve session state across these two frameworks.

Of course, depending on how sensitive the data is,you could hack it. Make an Ajax call in the background to retrieve session data from a custom page and feed it into the .NET session. It's a hack and a security risk, but it would work.

Comment: Worth noting that Session variables are not IIS specific. You can use them just fine on [UltiDev](http://ultidev.com/products/UWS-Cassini-Pro/)

Comment: I assumed out-of-the-box IIS install. I know PHP and other frameworks can store or used to store session state in a file; so session was accessible outside of the framework. It's my understanding that classic ASP stores session values in memory, not raw files.

Comment: In the end we went for an intermediary ASP page which posts the sessions variable to my Default.aspx on document load using JavaScript.

Comment: doesn't have to be a security risk, be sure to use some form of encryption in between your send-receive end

Answer (score 1):

Several solutions..., here is a recent one

http://weblogs.asp.net/lichen/archive/2011/10/30/sharing-session-between-asp-classic-and-asp-net-using-asp-net-session-state-server.aspx

There are also other solutions, google for session share asp.net asp you'll find many solutions including solutions by ms herself.